# How can I identify non-ASCII characters from the shell?

Tags: linux, grep, perl, awk, ascii

Is there a simple way to print all non-ASCII characters and the line numbers on which they occur in a file using a command line utility such as `grep`, `awk`, `perl`, etc?

I want to change the encoding of a text file from UTF-8 to ASCII, but before doing so, wish to manually replace all instances of non-ASCII characters to avoid unexpected character changes effected by the file conversion routine.

Answer (score 19):

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$. $_" if m/[\x80-\xFF]/'  utf8.txt
2 Pour être ou ne pas être
4 Byť či nebyť
5 是或不
```

or

```
$ grep -n -P '[\x80-\xFF]' utf8.txt
2:Pour être ou ne pas être
4:Byť či nebyť
5:是或不
```

where utf8.txt is

```
$ cat utf8.txt
To be or not to be.
Pour être ou ne pas être
Om of niet zijn
Byť či nebyť
是或不
```

Comment: Thanks.  The perl snippet works directly, but the grep version doesn't work with GNU grep 2.16.  I was able to make it work via: `LC_ALL=C grep -n -P [$'\x80'-$'\xFF']`, where the first bit turns off collation.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to change the encoding of a text file from UTF-8 to ASCII ...
>
> ... replace all instances of non-ASCII characters ...

Then tell your conversion tool to do so.

```
$ iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ASCII <<< 'Look at 私.'
Look at .

$ iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//translit <<< 'áēìöų'
aeiou
```

Comment: He said he wanted to do that replacement manually.  Perhaps the most appropriate replacement is context-dependent.